# Why is there no information about Int in the documentation for OCaml (4.07.0)?

Tags: ocaml

I'm a newbie to the OCaml language, I am currently watching .
There is an example that uses Int.descending , but I didn't find the relevant information in the documentation (4.07.0). I only saw Int32 and Int64.
Where can I find documentation about Int.descending And its other properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find `Int.descending` just because it is not in the standard library of OCaml.

My guess is that you are looking a code using Jane Street's Base library which has `descending`: 
https://github.com/janestreet/base/blob/dee8d637af902a92c739df7f3f8bc4d715c9d35d/src/comparable_intf.ml

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.At your prompt, I found it.     https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Int/